# Adding Google ReCaptcha

Tags: php, ajax

I have an existing contact form that performs validation on the server and client sides. Everything works with the form just fine but I am clueless as to how to add Google ReCaptcha v2. Reading the docs on Google's website I am still no where close to a solution.

Can someone give me an example on how they would go about this?

My goal here is for the form to spit out errors for all required fields including telling the user to fill out the captcha.

**PHP:**

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$response = [
    'status' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Mail sent successfully',
    'data' => []
];



//Checking is it ajax request
if (strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) !== 'xmlhttprequest') {
    //Invalid Ajax request
    http_response_code(403);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Invalid request, please try again.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}

if( !isset($_POST['data']) ) {
    http_response_code(400);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Empty post data.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}
$data = json_decode($_POST['data'], true); $errors = '';

//Email validation
if ( isset($data["userEmail"]) && !empty( $data["userEmail"] ) ) {
    $email = trim($data["userEmail"]);
    if ( filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false){
        $errors .= "$email is <strong>NOT</strong> a valid email address.<br/>";
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your email address.<br/>';
}
//Name Validation
if ( isset($data["userName"]) && !empty( $data["userName"] ) ) {
    $name = trim( $data["userName"] );
    if ( filter_var($name, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/>';
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
        $errors .= 'Only letters and white space allowed for name...<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
}

//Subject Validation
if ( isset($data["subject"]) && !empty( $data["subject"] ) ) {
    $subject = trim( $data["subject"] );
    if ( filter_var($subject, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a subject to send.<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter a subject to send.<br/>';
}

//Message Validation
if ( isset($data["message"]) && !empty( $data["message"] ) ) {
    $message = trim( $data["message"] );
    if ( filter_var($message, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING) === false){
        $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
    }
} else {
    $errors .= 'Please enter a message to send.<br/>';
}



if(!empty( $errors )) {
    http_response_code(400);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $errors,
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
}

//Filtering out newlines in the email subject
$subject = str_replace(array("\r","\n"),array(" "," "),$subject);
$contactContent = file_get_contents('email_templates/contact.html');;
$parameters = ['name' => $name, 'to_name' => TO_NAME, 'message' => $message ];

if(! send_mail( $email, $subject, $contactContent, $parameters ) ){ 
    //Email sent failed.
    http_response_code(500);
    $response = [
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => 'Email service failing temporarily Or Maybe you are entered invalid E-mail, Please enter valid email and try again.',
        'data' => []
    ];
    responseHandler($response);
} else {
    //Email successfully sent
    http_response_code(200);
    responseHandler($response);
} 

/**
 * responseHandler function
 * @param array $response request response
 */
function responseHandler($response)
{
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;
}

/**
 * send_mail function
 * @param  string $email             [[Description]]
 * @param  string $Subject           [[Description]]
 * @param  string $message           [[Description]]
 * @param  array [$parameters = []] [[Description]]
 * @return boolean  [[Description]]
 */

function send_mail($email, $Subject, $message, $parameters = []){
    ////Parse the message with given parameters
    if( !empty( $parameters ) )$message = parse($message, $parameters);



    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;                               // Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = SMTP_HOST;  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = SMTP_AUTH;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = SMTP_USERNAME;
    $mail->Password = SMTP_PASSWORD;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = SMTP_SECURE;                            // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = SMTP_PORT;                                    // TCP port to connect to

    if( isset($parameters['name']) )  
        $mail->setFrom($email, $parameters['name']);
    else 
        $mail->setFrom($email);


    $mail->addAddress(TO_EMAIL);     // Add a recipient
    //$mail->addReplyTo($email, 'Smart Invoice V3 Promotion');
    $mail->addBCC(TO_EMAIL);

    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $Subject;

    $mail->Body = $message;
    $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($message);

    if(!$mail->send()) {//$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}


/**
 * parse function
 * @param  string $message    [[Description]]
 * @param  array $parameters [[Description]]
 * @return string [[Description]]
 */
function parse($message, $parameters) {
    foreach ($parameters as $key => $value) {
        $message = str_replace('{'.$key.'}', $value, $message);
    }
    return $message;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("#loader").fadeOut("slow");
    $('#main').fadeIn("slow");
});
$(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            element.removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        }
    });
    $('#emailForm').validate( {
        submitHandler : function(form) {
            return false;
        },
        rules : {
            userEmail:{
                required: true,
                email: true
            },
            userName:{
                required : true,
                minlength : 3,
                maxlength : 50
            },
            subject: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 10
            },
            message: {
                required : true,
                minlength : 50
            }
        },
        messages : {
            userEmail:{
                required : "Please enter your Email"
            },
            userName:{
                required : "Please enter your name"
            },
            subject: {
                required : "Please enter your contact purpose",
                minlength : "Minimum length of subject must be 10 chars long."
            },
            message: {
                required : "Please enter your sweet message",
                minlength : "Minimum length of your message must be 50 chars long."
            }
        },
        errorPlacement : function(error, element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html(error.html());
        },
        highlight : function(element) {
            $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass('has-success');
             $(element).closest('div.form-group').find('.help-block').html('');
        }
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#sendMailBtn', function(e){



        e.preventDefault();
        if( $('#emailForm').valid() ) {
            var sendMailBtn = $('#sendMailBtn');
            sendMailBtn.button('loading');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                method: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data : { data: JSON.stringify($('#emailForm').serializeObject()) },
                success: function( response ){
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    $('input,textarea').val('');
                    showSuccessMessage();
                },
                error: function( response ) {
                    sendMailBtn.button('reset');
                    if( response.status === 400 || response.status === 403 || response.status === 500 ) {
                        showWarningMessage(response.responseJSON.message);
                    } else {
                        showWarningMessage();
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });

    function showSuccessMessage(){
        swal({
            title: "Many Thanks!!!",
            text: "Thanks for contacting us, We will get back to your inbox shortly...",
            type: "success",
            html: true
            /*imageUrl: "img/thumbs-up.jpg"*/
        });
    }

    function showWarningMessage(message){
        if(typeof message === 'undefined' || message === '' ) message = "Something went wrong, Please try again.";
        swal({
            title: "Oops...",
            text: message,
            type: "error",
            html: true
        });
    }

    $.fn.serializeObject = function()
    {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function() {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A successful solution to any Recaptcha will return a grecapcha object. Therefore:

```
var rcResponse = grecaptcha.getResponse();
  if (rcResponse.length > 0) {
       //Recaptcha succeeded .... continue
  }
```

Your form should have a wrapper for the Recaptcha itself:

```
<div style="display:inline-block;" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"></div>
```

Comment: This requires improvement. While it's true that all successful recaptcha checks return a response, you should never reply just on the fact that the response is there and assume it's always a "human". There's a reason why the recaptcha API has a method to validate the content of the response to verify the check result is a successful human validation

Comment: @JavierLarroulet but how would I correctly implement this on the server side to see if there has been any interaction with it and if that interaction was successful? I can see where it can feed the data to google but after that i am lost.

Comment: @Javier The job of Recaptcha "is" to validate a human response. No response means no validation.

Comment: While true in most cases, that's not the case. Most of the validation occurs away from your backend. If you're relying just on "getting or not getting Google's response by the time a whole payload reaches the backend" you are leaving massive easily exploitable holes. There is a reason why you have 2 keys and the secret one must be away from the validation process and used to validates the contents of Google's response